# Lookup a value on another table with no relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In TSQL, how do we select a value from a table with no relationship to the other.

I'm trying to select what rank an ID has, by looking up their score in another table. I was going to join and then use a 'where Score between From and TO' but, I had no luck joining.

Table_A

| ID | Score |
| --- | --- |
| A | 67 |
| B | 569 |
| C | 123 |

Table_B

| From | To | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 99 | Top100 |
| 100 | 499 | Top500 |
| 500 | 999 | Top1000 |

Expected query result:

| ID | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| A | Top100 |
| B | Top1000 |
| C | Top500 |

I started with

```sql
Select ID From Table_A
Inner Join
```

I got lost here because there is no relationship

I could get the result using a scalar function, but in terms of performance, where Table_A has over 500k rows, it seemed a little sluggish because Table_B not only holds rank, but has other columns I need for the query.

For example:

Table_B

| From | To | Rank | Level | Color | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 99 | Top100 | Gold | Green | 1 |
| 100 | 499 | Top500 | Silver | Yellow | 5 |
| 500 | 999 | Top1000 | Bronze | Red | 100 |

Basically, if I can be shown how to query at least the rank, I can get the other columns as well.

Comment: Aside: You might want to reconsider the table design. Having `From` and `To` columns, well chosen keywords, allows you to represent overlapping ranges. That's probably not useful. Having a single value, e.g. `BaseValue`, gets rid of (most) of the confusion. (A `unique` constraint would help more.) It becomes an issue of finding the row with the highest `BaseValue` value `<=` than the target value. It also reduces issues that result from mixing data types, e.g. what `Rank` to assign for a target value of `99.5`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BETWEEN` as the JOIN condition, like so:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Table_A
(
ID VARCHAR(255),
Score INT
)
;

INSERT #Table_A ([ID], [Score]) VALUES
('A', 67),
('B', 569),
('C', 123);

CREATE TABLE #Table_B
(
    [From] INT,
    [To] INT,
    [Rank] VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT #Table_B ([From], [To], [Rank]) VALUES
( 1, 99, 'Top100'), (100, 499, 'Top500'), (500, 999, 'Top1000');

-- Query here

SELECT A.[ID], B.[Rank]
FROM #Table_A A
INNER JOIN #Table_B B ON A.Score BETWEEN B.[From] AND B.[To]
```

Comment: Yep. Pretty much. I would add, this will be fully functional. However, performance might be more than a little stinky.

Comment: Yeh @GrantFritchey I would agree that it's going to be worse than if you had some better relationship (and for something so static maybe even just put in a case statement or handle it in the app to get the rank details), but in situations where I've had no choice re: schema changes etc, I've used a BETWEEN in a JOIN and ended up with a query that worked well enough, and better than the alternatives I came up with or inherited.

Comment: @TZHX Goodness. It worked perfect. 500k rows, Took 3 seconds. Thank you.

Comment: Oh yeah @TZHX. You're 100% right. I didn't mean it as a criticism. I'm questioning the structure, not your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use CROSS APPLY to get your favorite result

```
;WITH Table_A AS 
(
    SELECT 'A' ID,  67 Score
    Union
    SELECT 'B' ID,  569 Score
    Union
    SELECT 'C' ID,  123 Score
), 
Table_B AS 
(
    SELECT 1 [From], 99 [To], 'Top100' [Rank]
    Union
    SELECT 100 [From], 499 [To], 'Top500' [Rank]
    Union
    SELECT 500 [From], 999 [To], 'Top1000' [Rank]
)

SELECT Table_A.[ID], Table_B.[Rank]
FROM Table_A 
    CROSS APPLY Table_B  
WHERE Table_A.Score 
    BETWEEN Table_B.[From] AND Table_B.[To]
GO
```